# Recovering a Skype password from the Keychain

Tags: security, password, keychain, skype

I lost my computer and Skype was tied to an email account I no longer have access to because I graduated. I recovered the Keychain from a backup and I can see these items, all with kind `application password`:

- `skypeapp-f92ff56fb86b`, account `.token.0`, which `Skype Helper.app` can always access
- `skypeapp-ece94a0d3781`, account `.token.0`, which `Skype Helper.app` can always access
- `Skype4Life-AddinToken-https://substrate.office.com/Todo-Internal.ReadWrite`, account `<my username>`, which `Skype.app` can always access
- `Skype for Desktop MSA`, account `<my username>`, which `Skype.app` can always access
- `Skype for Desktop`, account `<my username>`, which `Skype.app` can always access
- `skype`, account `.token.1`, which `Skype Helper.app` can always access

The first two have a password of `p` (really). I thought the latter would have my password, but clicking the checkbox `Show password` prompts for the password twice (once with `Keychain Access wants to use your confidential information stored in "skype" in your keychain` and again with `Keychain Access wants to access the key "skype" in your keychain`) but does not show the password: the checkbox remains unchecked and the text field to the right remains empty.

I could recover the account if I could look at previous calls in order to answer the security questions. Launching Skype and signing in with another account creates `Skype for Desktop MSA` and `Skype for Desktop` in my login keychain, so I replaced the account name and the values with the ones from the previous keychain, but I did not get signed in, possibly because the authentication tokens expired.

I also tried a `macOS` installation on a live USB where the login password was the same as the Keychain password and replacing the files in `~/Library/Keychains` with those from the backup, but it still did not show those passwords.

I also tried copying the cookies for the Skype application from `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Skype for Desktop/`, independently of the passwords above, and it failed.

I am using `macOS` Mojave 10.14.6`and`Keychain Access` 10.5.

How can I recover my password, or access the account long enough to view details?